# ksh sort first column and avg second column

Tags: sorting, awk, average, ksh

Looking for an awk or similar command that can sort a file with 2 columns, then produce an output of Unique column one names and total avg in column two.

so for example:

```
aaaa 11.5
aaaa 1.01
aaaa 5.50
bbbb 12.5
bbbb 1.10
bbbb 9.5
```

looking for output

```
aaaa 6.00
bbbb 7.7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this with awk:

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2;b[$1]++} END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]/b[i]}' File
bbbb 7.7
aaaa 6.00333
```

If you want to round off, use printf.

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2;b[$1]++} END{for(i in a)printf("%s %.2f\n",i,a[i]/b[i])}' File
```

with the first field as index, update array `a` (add up the 2nd fields). Keep a counter `b[first field]` also updated. At the end, print all indices of `a` and the average. Hope it's clear.

For sorted result, pipe the output to `sort` (`awk '{a[$1]+=$2;b[$1]++} END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]/b[i]}' File | sort`)